# bootstrap datetimepicker separate date field and separate time field

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, datetime

```
$('#sTart').datetimepicker({
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm',
        stepping: 15
}).on("dp.change", function (e) {
  $('#eNd').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
});
$('#eNd').datetimepicker({
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm',
        stepping: 15,
        useCurrent: false
}).on("dp.change", function (e) {
  $('#sTart').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
});
```

The above is the code for Start datetime field **#sTart** field and **#eNd** datetime field.
It works like suppose if you select **start datetime** as ***15 july 6:30am*** and the **end datetime** will be greater than ***15 july 6:30am***

I need help to customize further for starttime(separate date field and separate time field) and endtime(separate date field and separate time field)

Comment: Why not use a datetimepicker with the format DD/MM/YYYY and then another form field with HH:mm and then combine them after submit to make the datetime you need?

Answer (score 1):

I think you just have to set one datetimepicker with "format: 'DD/HH/YYYY'" and the other one with "format: 'HH:mm'". Hope it helps

Comment: Yep that will work. I know but i have to keep some conditions like if he selects 'start date and time' then in 'end date and time', i have to disable the previous date and times based on start date and time.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? Or do you still need help? (Otherwise it would be great if you accept my answer :) )